# Mongo/Mongoose: cleanup orphaned refs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose we a typical one-to-many relationship modeled using references as [suggested by MongoDB official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/):

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({

});

var Group = mongoose.Schema({

  user: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]

});
```

Let's also assume I care about the order, in which users appear in the group, so the array is necessary.

Now, for let's assume that the user has been deleted -- and the groups have not been maintained with `$pull` for some reason. If you use Mongoose's `populate` everything *looks* fine, but the garbage persists in the array.

Is there a way to identify the orphaned refs and remove them? Maybe even automatically -- similarly to what `CASCADE` does in relational world? What's the best approach to maintain the referential integrity in Mongo/Mongoose? Finally, what's the most efficient one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a `remove` hook on your User model to try to maintain data integrity on an ongoing basis: `User.post('remove', pullUserFromGroups);` Hopefully that will keep integrity mostly intact. You can remove the user from every group with a single `$pull` operation. This is a mongo analog to a `CASCADE` from relational DBs.

For after-the fact cleanup you need to iterate over every Group, find every userId in `group.user`, query to see if the record exists, and pull it out if not. It's simplest to just  do this one at a time, but you could also use `User.find({_id: {$in: group.user}})` and then calculate the user IDs not found and pull them that way.

Comment: Thanks for the post-hook advice, it's pretty cool. My concerns were mostly about the after-the fact scenario, since the application does its job well, but since there are no transactions in Mongo, bad things _can_ actually happen.